# Выбор хостинга для картинок

Tags: хостинг

Есть сайт, на котором пара гигабайтов фотографий. Чтобы снизить сетевую нагрузку на сервер, было решено переложить фотографии на хостинг изображений. Предложили flickr, но после поверхностного ознакомления с ним, стало ясно, что он ужимает разрешение фотографий, а также перегенерировать ссылки на новые изображения будет очень сложно. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что он переживает? Я правда не тестировал на очень большом разрешении, но вроде всё нормально. Плюс можно получить прямую ссылку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите на imgur (им пользуется ХэшКод). Картинки - размером до 5 Мб. Количество картинок неограниченно. Там недорого - порядка 700 рублей за год.

Answer (score 5):

Для этого можно использовать только коммерческие сервисы типа Amazon S3, cloudflare или любой CDN. Ни один бесплатный хостинг картинок не согласится, чтобы его ресурсы использовали в таких целях.

Answer (score 0):

Если не нужны какие-то особые навороты, то попробуйте http://piccy.info/

Comment: Чудесный сервис, вошел, ввел капчу и увидел это:

    > 403 Forbidden
    > (banned)
    > 2388800545395080133404432234706

Comment: дааа... походу либо я дурак либо то что надо не посоветовали...