# Готовый движок для создания собственного сервера хранению картинок

Tags: php, c#, asp.net-core, хостинг, хостинг-изображений

Появилась у меня потребность хранить заливаемые пользователями картинки на сайт и я даже посмотрел некоторые фотохостинги ([обзор на хабре](https://habr.com/post/89162/), [вопрос на тостере](https://toster.ru/q/506), [вопрос на ru so](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/99099/213987)).

Поскольку денег на пет-проект особо нет, то подумал об альтернативном варианте: поднять свой собственный сервер (сейчас и в России есть предложения по ~200 - 300 рублей в месяц и в мире тем более полно, а за эти деньги пусть и не особо мощный сервер с 512 RAM, но зато с 20 гб ssd, из которых уж 10 точно под картинки останется).

Правда, для этого придётся писать самому такой сервер. Может быть есть готовые решения для подобной задачи? Я бы посмотрел решения как под linux (на базе nginx, php и т.п.), так и под windows (asp.net, asp.net core)

Требований особых нет, разве что хотелось бы опенсорс, чтобы допилить если что.

Comment: А в чем собсна говоря проблема? Не совсем понятно в чем проблема. Вы не можете написать скрипт приема изображений? Логика приложения вроде как простая. Думаю вы за день сможете все реализовать сами. Будет не чужое, а свое, родимое :)

Comment: «хранить заливаемые пользователями картинки на сайт» можно и в Imgur (по вашим же ссылкам упоминается), чем не угодил?

Comment: Посмотри http://galleryproject.org/, у меня эта штука на NAS-е стояла, по-дефолту. Вроде ничего лишнего и на вид не слишком страшная.

Comment: Так а какие требования к системе, кроме хранения файлов и выдачи по ссылкам? Аналоги Amazon S3 не подойдут?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, самая удобная и продвинутая в этом плане система - WordPress. Тут есть все: удобная панель, интуитивный интерфейс для обычных пользователей... Но вряд ли кто-то станет использовать такую громадину только для загрузки изображений =)

По сути, готового движка нет, но зато есть некоторые библиотеки и Хабр! В [этом посте](https://habr.com/post/136694/) представлен код небольшого обработчика. Конечно, он далек от совершенства: нужно допилить внешний вид, а также решить вопрос с загрузкой изображений с одинаковыми названиями. Но это ведь не проблема, да? В таком случае можно использовать текущую дату/время с точностью до миллисекунд как раз для генерации имени файла...

Comment: `WordPress`? фуфуфу.... Тяжелый и медленный.

Comment: тогда уж maxSitecms

Comment: @Manitikyl зато ребята-разработчики здорово его раскрутили, теперь я на глаз определяю все WP-сайты =) Кстати, согласно данным Википедии, фуфуфу стоит на трети сайтов всего Интернета =)

Comment: Wordpress? )) Мне нужен только метод uploadImage )))  А отдача будет через nginx идти. Остальное же - рюшечки типа "заресайзить" или "поддержка нескольких серверов" - это уже опционально. По факту вы предлагаете универсальную CMS, в то время как я ищу узкоспециализированные решения.

Comment: @AK а что насчет поста на Хабре? Мне кажется, для небольшого сайта код нормальный...

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский стоит на трети сайтов? Это явная чушь. Возможно среди всех CMS там на третьем. Ни один нормальный проект, не будет стоять на вордпрессе. Он сделан по факту для того чтобы люди без знаний подняли свой сайт(для маленькой аудитории, типа визитки) и не более того.

Comment: @Manitikyl  это css-trics и tympanus для маленькой аудитории ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский именно так.

Comment: @Manitikyl у вас есть хоть что то в подтверждение ваших слов? Я сам не в теме, потому и спрашиваю. Если чуть чуть погуглить ([раз](https://websitesetup.org/popular-cms/), [два](https://trends.builtwith.com/cms), [три](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-cms-of-2018)), то, кажется, что вордпресс гораздо лучше, чем вы о нем пишете.

Comment: @tym32167 Так это вполне очевидно. То что прислали вы - это обзор CMS, исходя из этих данных можно сказать что вордпресс является популярной CMS, но не популярным ядром сайтов. Сайты пишутся не только на готовых CMS, а большинство людей предпочитают писать сайт на феймворках и конкретно под задачу. Такое решение позволяет увеличить кол-во ответов в секунду в несколько раз, что собсна уменьшает и нагрузку и увеличивает возможности. Когда мы поговорим о высоком трафике этот показатель будет очень сильно решать. И это не все плюсы, есть плюс и в масштабировании и в гибкости и т.д.

Comment: @Manitikyl мы, наверное, о разных вещах говорим. Я не знаю, что вы подразумеваете под ядром сайтов - это ведь не какой то широко известный термин.  В моем понимании, если человеку нужен сервис, для которого нет жестких требований, то он может использовать CMS широкого профиля - типа вордпресс, и кастомизировать это все плагинами так, как ему надо. Например, сделать сайт компании с новостями, блогами и прочим. А вот если делается что то специфическое с жесткими требованиями производительности, то тут в принципе никакая CMS не поможет, так как готовая CMS - это вообще не про производительность.

Comment: @tym32167 ядро сайта - то что у вас лежит в основе сайта. ядром бывает и вордпресс и другая кмс либо-же фреймворк. По факту вы написали тоже самое что и я. Для простенького непопулярного сайта, ставится вордпресс и накручивается плагинами (А любой плагин это +к нагрузке, а вордпресс и так не хвастается скоростью). А если делать серьезное приложение, то правильней делать на фреймворках. Это очевидно, поэтому определенно сайтов на фреймворках больше чем на ворпрессе.

Comment: @Manitikyl а, ну тогда да, тогда согласен с вами